# USB speaker emits funny sound when idling and gets worse when processor is busy

Tags: windows-10, usb, audio, speakers

I am running Windows 10 on a desktop PC. The USB speakers emit funny sounds even when the PC is idle. The sound gets worse when the processor is busy. What are the possible causes and solutions?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

This happened when digital and analog ground incorrectly routed on motherboard  or there not enough or failed capacitors that in charge of filtering power lines. It could be also a bad audio socket (cold soldering) that loosing ground connection. It could be speakers itself (grounding issue or power filtering again).

First, try another speakers or better headphones. If "funny sounds" still exist, try to reinsert audio connector multiple times( it will clean up a little bit contacts inside of audio socket). If it doesn't help, try another power supply, check motherboard if there is a bulged capacitors (look at google images how it looks)